# How to create or update a many to many relationship with a RESTful API

Tags: rest

I'm trying to understand exactly how a many to many relationship works.

Let's say I have a `Movie` and `Actor` model. `Actors` belong to many `Movies` and `Movies` have many `Actors`. I understand that I can create a `MovieActor` table that has foreign keys from both a `Movie` and `Actor`. The part that I'm not quite clear about is if I want to create a new `Actor` and relate it to a `Movie` (`POST`) or update an existing `Actor` to relate it to a `Movie` (`PUT`), do I use my `/api/actor` endpoint or do I create a separate endpoint for `/api/movieactor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either.  Often times, a REST API (and even the backing DB) will denormalize that data so that it exists in both entries.  But it's up to you how you want to notify the REST server of the data.  You could POST a new Actor, and in the Actor, include the Movies - and the Server (in addition to adding the new record for the Actor) could update the data stored in the Movie record.  Or vice-versa.  Or both.  There's no rule that a modification to one REST object can't have side-effects on other objects.

And I think people would generally recommend against having a 3rd API just to get the relationship data between the two primary objects.  It just complicates the client API, introduces more latency, and exposes too much of the DB internals to the client (making it harder to change in the future).